# Selecting a Radio Button in an HTML page from a native app

Tags: javascript, swift, webkit, swift2, wkwebview

How do you check a **radio button** in an HTML page that is loaded in a web view?

**example:**

I have two radio buttons embedded in an HTML page:

1. Allow All
2. Restrict Access

I want to construct an app wherein if a **UIButton** or **UISwitch** is tapped, the program will automatically select **"Restrict Access"** and print the selection to console.

New to Xcode and Swift programming here.

using **Xcode7**, **Swift 2.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebKit's `WKWebView` to achieve this. Just add a `WKWebView` to your view controller and load the page with your radio buttons. You will probably load a page from your server, but for testing purposes I'm loading a HTML file that I added to the Xcode project. When you press the button you evaluate a Javascript string that checks the radio button.

This is a working example:

**The ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView = WKWebView()
    let button = UIButton(type: .RoundedRect)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height - 60)
        view.addSubview(webView)

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "html")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

        // or load the HTML from your server
        // webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://yourdomain.com/yourpage")!))

        button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 520, view.bounds.size.width - 100, 40)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        button.setTitle("Press", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didPressButton:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

   func didPressButton(button: UIButton) {
        let jsString = "document.getElementById('res').checked = true;"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString) { (result, error) -> Void in
            print(result)
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {padding: 30px; font-size: 30px}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form action="radio.html">
        <input type="radio" id="all" name="allow_all" value="allow_all"><label for="all"> Allow all</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="res" name="restrict" value="restrict"><label for="res"> Restrict Access</label><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now when you press the button the radio button gets set. The method that does this has a completion closure that gets executed when the Javascript has been evaluated.

If the Javascript evaluation was successful, the value that was returned by the Javascript will we handed to the closure in the optional `result` object.

In this case the value `1` is returned which indicates that the radio button is now checked.

If the Javascript evaluation fails an `error` object is created and handed to the closure. So you can check if the Javascript call was successful or not.